# TypeError: Named parameters can only be passed within plain objects, while trying to handle Sqlite errors using ES6 arrow functions

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ecmascript-6, node-sqlite3

I have some working code to manipulate a Sqlite database written in this notation (I think ES5?):

```
try {
    const cols = Object.keys(data).join(", ");
    const placeholders = Object.keys(data).map(x => "$" + x).join(", ");
    const stmt = db.prepare(`
      INSERT INTO ` + table + ` (` + cols + `) 
      VALUES (` + placeholders + `)`);
    stmt.run(data);
} catch (err) { 
    // some reporting and handling
}
```

Where the values to populate the SQL statement come from a JS object (`data`) passed on earlier.

I would like to refactor this to use ES6 and replace the `try...catch` block with arrow functions. I found some examples ([here](https://www.codeguru.co.in/2023/11/how-to-use-sqlite-with-nodejs.html) and [here](https://www.sql-easy.com/learn/how-to-use-node-js-sqlite/)) but they use a different syntax, where the SQL command is executed directly with the `.run()` method, instead of using `.prepare()` as I have in my code.

However, when I try to apply an arrow function directly to my code

```
const cols = Object.keys(data).join(", ");
const placeholders = Object.keys(data).map(x => "$" + x).join(", ");
const insert_stmt = db.prepare(`
  INSERT INTO ` + table + ` (` + cols + `) 
  VALUES (` + placeholders + `)`);
insert_stmt.run(data, (err) => {
    if (err.message === "some error") { 
       // handle the error
    }
});
```

I get the error

> TypeError: Named parameters can only be passed within plain objects

From what I could understand, this is probably a syntax error? Which I think means with the new notation I'm not passing the values within the `data` object correctly.

Can I use an arrow function in this case? Should I abandon the `.prepare()` syntax and go with the examples in the webpages I linked?

EDIT: I'm using `better-sqlite3`.

Comment: What line does the error point to?

Comment: If you’re using template literals anyway, you should use their `${}` interpolation syntax instead of less readable `+` concatenation.

Comment: @deceze `insert_stmt.run(data, (err) => {`

I use this function to insert to more than one table and they all have a different number of fields, so I need some flexibility when constructing the SQL statement, hence the concatenation. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples you linked use package `sqlite3`, but my guess from your code is that you're using `better-sqlite3` as it is more similar to their documentation.

`better-sqlite3` does not offer an API that takes an error function as the second argument of `PreparedStatement.run`.

Instead, what happens is that it is trying to use your error function as a named parameter. A function is not a plain object, which explains your error.

Comment: Yes, I am using better-sqlite3. So what is the best approach here? Switch to sqlite3? Keep using try....catch? Something else?

Comment: @user Frankly, I don't see why you'd want to switch from `try..catch` to callback hell in the first place.

Comment: 2 reasons to switch, none are particularly good: 1) the wrapping function is written with arrow function and it looks clean and simple and I wouldn't mind having the code inside use the same style. 2) I am currently not able to return gracefully from within a specific error handling routine without triggering the generic error handling message (and stop execution). I thought by switching I'd be able to get the code to work without having to figure out the current problem. If I'm going to keep the try...catch clause I'm going to have to create another Question to get help for this problem....

Comment: @user2066480 Both libraries are fine. Pick one and follow its documentation. I use a third alternative `promised-sqlite3`. But now we're going into personal preference, and this is a Q&A forum.